# How to add a dataset identifier (like id column) when append two or more datasets?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple datasets in csv format that I would like to import by appending. Each dataset has the same columns name (fields), but different values and length.

For example:

```
df1

    date name surname age address
...

df2
    date name surname age address
...
```

I would like to have

```
 df=df1+df2
        date name surname age address dataset

  (df1)                                  1
    ...                                  1
  (df2)                                  2
    ...                                  2
```

i.e. I would like to add a new column that is an identifier for dataset (where fields come from, if from dataset 1 or dataset 2).

How can I do it?

Comment: Please show what you have tried(code)? How are you appending these dataframes together?

Comment: @Shubham Sharma, the code to append the dataframes was concat (as shown in the answer below). What I did not know was how to add a new column for marking rows from the datasets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

Note: Example has fewer columns that yours but the method is the same.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': [f'Name{i}' for i in range(5)],
    'age': range(10, 15)
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': [f'Name{i}' for i in range(20, 22)],
    'age': range(20, 22)
})

combined = pd.concat([df1, df2])
combined['dataset'] = [1] * len(df1) + [2] * len(df2)
print(combined)
```

Output

```
     name  age  dataset
0   Name0   10        1
1   Name1   11        1
2   Name2   12        1
3   Name3   13        1
4   Name4   14        1
0  Name20   20        2
1  Name21   21        2
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank you @Balaji Ambresh

Answer (score 0):

In Spark with scala , I would do something like this :

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

```
  val df1 = sparkSession.read
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .json("/home/shredder/Desktop/data1.json")

  val df2 = sparkSession.read
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .json("/home/shredder/Desktop/data2.json")

  val df1New = df1.withColumn("dataset",lit(1))
  val df2New = df2.withColumn("dataset",lit(2))

  val df3 = df1New.union(df2New)
  df3.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

We have `key` in `concat`

```
combined = pd.concat([df1, df2],keys=[1,2]).reset_index(level=1)
```